# Android sw600dp doesn't cover some tablets properly

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-size

I have been going through some of the Android tablet devices to confirm that they do indeed fit the sw600dp mark for tablets([recommendation by Google](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources)). I am going to talk about a set of 7in tablets:

[**Huawei MediaPad T3 7.0**](https://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_mediapad_t3_7_0-8635.php): smallest width = 564dp

[**Lenovo Tab3 7**](https://www.gsmarena.com/lenovo_tab3_7-7951.php): smallest width = 564dp

[**Samsung Galaxy Tab A 7.0 (2016)**](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_tab_a_7_0_(2016)-7880.php): smallest width = 592dp

All of these fall closely short of the 600dp mark while it seems that the layout for 600dp might just be a better fit for the same.

Have I calculated anything wrong or tabs require a higher sw mark?

Answer (score 0):

I believe google recommendation is just an approximation. Companies that design these devices can honestly take any route with regards to the recommendation. It's up to us as developers to tweak things here and there in order to make things work well.